# Why does S.T.A.R. Labs look different in Vixen than it does in The Flash?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash, vixen

In *The Flash*, S.T.A.R. Labs looks like this:

[image: S.T.A.R. Labs in The Flash]

But in Vixen, S.T.A.R. Labs looks like this:

[image: S.T.A.R. Labs in Vixen, season 1]

And it continues to look this way in Season 2:

[image: S.T.A.R. Labs in Vixen, season 2]

I find this puzzling because both shows are part of the Arrowverse and *Vixen* was released well after *The Flash*. Moreover, the Arrow cave in Season 2 looks pretty much like it does in live action. So why does S.T.A.R. Labs look different between these two shows?

Comment: Frankly, it looks like the typical Cartoon hall of justice design.

Comment: Since other questions [have been answered](http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/56879/12783) by contacting the director or other crew, maybe we could do the same? James Tucker, was the director and animator for Season 1, so he might be someone to ask, but it seems like the only way to contact him is on Twitter and I don't have an account.

Comment: Could you add screenshots of the quiver, i mean arrow cave as well?

Comment: Did you compared it with post flashpoint speed lab

Comment: @AnkitSharma S.T.A.R. Labs looks the same after Flashpoint in the live action show.

Comment: @Thunderforge not really, they have an extra room called "speed lab" after flashpoint.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Huh, I always figured that was just a repurposed area that was always there, they just hadn't used it before. Still, there doesn't seem to be a room, before or after Flashpoint, that looks like the one seen in Vixen.